# Fontattribute is obsolete xamarin forms-1.3

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Forms 1.3 stable version.

I am getting a warning stating that fontattributes is obsolete. So I changed the code to

```
label.FontSize = Font.SystemFontOfSize(16, FontAttributes.Bold).FontSize
```

But `FontAttributes.Bold` doesn't work. It's not making the label bold. Can anybody help me in this?

Comment: Seems to me that `Font.BoldSystemFontOfSize` is obsolete, while `FontAttributes.Bold` is the recommended way ([docs](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/fonts/#2.2.font-attributes)). Is that what you mean? What was your code before you changed it?

Comment: Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(14, FontAttributes.Bold)
I was using this.

Comment: That method is not deprecated so it should work just fine. You were probably using `Font.BoldSystemFontOfSize` which has been deprecated in favor of the solution you are suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this. In Xamarin forms 1.3 Formsize and FormAttributes are 2 different properties for a label.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `FontSize` of your label, not its `Font` attribute. As [per the documentation](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/fonts/#2.2.font-attributes), you should be able to just do the following:

```
label.Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(16, FontAttributes.Bold);
```